# Any suggestions as to why a .Net app looks for a different config file on a 64-bit machine?

Tags: vb.net

We have a project management application written in VB.net. When running this application from a 32-bit machine or from within the Visual Studio IDE on a 64-bit machine, it looks for the correct configuration file (i.e. MyApp.exe.config). However, when running this app from outside the IDE on a 64-bit machine, it looks for MyApp.config and fails to find it.

Obviously I can copy the correct config to the badly named config, but we're at a loss as to why this behavior is occurring in the first place.

This is a windows application written in the 2.0 framework. No web.config file is associated (as I have found some references to a similar issue with web.config files that didn't apply).

Any guidance or suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Edit: I also should note that this is the only application this is occurring on. If I create a new vb.net application using the same libraries we use for config management, it works fine. Also, of some possible relevance, the projects are being built targeting the x86 CPU.

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do is on 64 bit at install time I'd do CreateHardLink("MyApp.exe.config", "MyApp.config", NULL)

CreateHardLink is P/Invokable.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am not looking so much for a workaround as I am for a reason as to why it may be occurring. Suggestions as to what else to check because we're out of ideas. This behavior is abnormal, but I figure there has to be some reason it's happening.